# Running "sudo dpkg --configure -a" fails

Tags: raspbmc, dpkg, aptitude

I set up RaspBMC on my Pi. I had a broken repo, so I SSH'd into it and ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to fix it. From that, I get

`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

So I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it fails every time at `Setting up rsyslog (5.8.11-3)`. Can someone see what's wrong from the output?

Here's my terminal:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg [490 B]
Get:2 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy Release [14.4 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages [7412 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages [23.2 kB]                                                                                    
Get:5 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages [48.0 kB]                                                                                   
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en                                                                                                
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en                                                                                                   
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en                                                                                               
Fetched 7498 kB in 2min 22s (52.7 kB/s)                                                                                                                      
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python-gi (3.2.2-2) ...
Setting up libisccfg82 (1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2) ...
Setting up udev (175-7.2) ...
udev stop/waiting
udev start/running, process 2233
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: Service udev has to be enabled to start service udev-mtab
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up rsyslog (5.8.11-3) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a well known problem, the installation process hangs during "Setting up rsyslog" phase, and rerunning `dpkg` won't fix it. raspbmc actually advises against running `apt-get update`.

you may just ignore it and keep watching your movies (xbmc should work just fine), or reinstall raspbmc from scratch, optionally backing up and restoring your settings with `tar -czf backup.tar.gz .xbmc` or something like that.

Comment: Yep I just reinstalled RaspBMC. Gonna try again. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is some weird (but working!) way to avoid RaspBMC reinstallation in this case.
Firstly, you should prepare the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "Start insserv clearing"
cd /etc
rm rc?.d/S* rc?.d/K*
typeset -l l=
while [[ $l != n ]]; do
        for x in init.d/*; do
                [[ -s $x ]] || continue
                x=${x##*/}
                [[ $x = *@(.dpkg|README|skeleton)* ]] && continue
                [[ $x = rc?(S) ]] && continue
                insserv -d "$x"
        done
        l=
        while [[ $l != @(y|n) ]]; do
                echo "retry (y/n)? "
                read l
        done
done
```

If you save this script somewhere on your Pi and run it repeatedly, as it described [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/01/msg00117.html), it can happen nevertheless that messages like:

```
insserv: Service mdadm-raid has to be enabled to start service mdadm
insserv: exiting now!
```

do not disappear eventually, and one or several of them persist. If so, for each of these messages you should perform actions, described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187724&page=8&p=12854415#post12854415). For example, for the message above you should:

- make backup of */etc/init.d/mdadm* file somewhere;
- find line starting with '# Required-Start' in */etc/init.d/mdadm* file, and remove string 'mdadm-raid' from this line;
- repeat two operations above for all messages occured;
- run command: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**
- immediately restore */etc/init.d/mdadm* file (and other, if necessary) from the backup.

It worked for me, but I can not provide any guaranties, of course. However the good news is that full reinstallation of RaspBMC is always available to you, if something would go wrong. :)

Comment: Registered to say thank you for showing me this gem: `typeset`. Had no idea anything like this was available in Bash!